# How to get SharePoint List ID using InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

I have a need to capture the SharePoint List ID in one of the list column. Is it possible to get SharePoint list id from InfoPath form of the same list?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand - you just need the ListID in a column in that same list?
Can't you just find the ListId and create a text column that always has that ID in it by default?

https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/finding-the-id-guid-for-a-sharepoint-list/